# Are async useEffect Callbacks Actually Harmful, or Just a "Smell"?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, use-effect

I can find lots of articles on the web that will tell you to change:

```
 useEffect(async() => {
   await doSomethingAsynchronous();
 })
```

into:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const pointlessFunction = async () => {
       await doSomethingAsynchronous();
   };
   pointlessFunction();
 })
```

But what I can't find is any explanation of the actual harm caused by the former.

I understand that React's ESLint rules will complain if you do the former, and I understand that it's complaining because the former might confusingly suggest that `useEffect` is waiting for the AJAX to complete (when it's not).

In both cases the `async` function is generating a promise, and in both cases that promise is being ignored (meaning that *neither version* is actually waiting for `doSomethingAsynchronous` to complete).

But ... if you understand the above, and can still write working code in spite of it ... is there any actual harm to doing the former?

**EDIT:**

It seems from the answers so far there is some "harm", but it's only in the form of limiting options.  If I go with form #2, I can't:

- return a cleanup function (because the `async` will make the function always return a promise)
- wrap the callback with a `try`/`catch`

So maybe that's the only harm: form #1 can't error handle or do cleanup.  But I'm still curious: aside from limiting my options, if I don't need to cleanup or handle errors, will form #1 actually break anything (ie. cause harm)?

After all, using a one-line arrow function (`() => 5`) limits your options too ... but we still use them all the time, and just use the more verbose form when we need it.  Why not do the same here?

Comment: Javascript is full of unwated side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other answers here are great and informative, none directly answered my original question, ie. "Is there any harm to providing `useEffect` with an `async` callback?

The answer is ... **no, there is no harm**.

However, there is an important *limitation* to that approach, which is that you cannot provide a cleanup function if you use it (because `async` functions can never return functions, only promises).  Also, some devs may be concerned  that future versions of React *may* break when an `async` callback is given to `useEffect`.

Both concerns can easily be addressed with a wrapper around `useEffect`, called something like `useAsyncEffect`.  This allows you to avoid ES Lint issues (and ensure compatibility with future React versions), while also still providing a cleanup function.

```
export const useAsyncEffect = (effect, dependencies, cleanup) => {
  // If no dependencies are provided but a cleanup function is, fix args
  if (!cleanup && typeof dependencies === 'function') {
    cleanup = dependencies;
    dependencies = undefined;
  }

  // Main wrapper code
  useEffect(() => {
    effect();
    return cleanup;
  }, dependencies);
};
```

Example Usage:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(null);
useAsyncEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`www.example.com/foo?id=${someId}`);
    const foo = await response.json();
    setFoo(foo);
}, [someId], someCleanupFunction);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues.

- React expects two possible return values from the callback: nothing (in which case there is no cleanup function to run), or a function (in which case that function is the cleanup function that will be run). If you return something *other* than those two return values, you're doing something that React doesn't know how to handle - which means that the logic you're implementing may well be buggy - the script-writer is returning a value of an unexpected type, and may be expecting React to do something with it - but it won't.

  It's a bit like doing

  ```
  someArray.forEach((item) => {
    // do something
    return true;
  });
  ```

  Because `forEach` ignores the value returned from the callback, any time you see code like this, it's probably a bug (or useless). If some library-writer nowadays decided to implement `forEach` themselves they might decide to be strict and show a warning when it sees a value returned from the callback.

  React is doing something similar. Using an async function (or returning a non-undefined, non-function value) isn't inherently *absolutely forbidden* and so doesn't produce an *error*, but it does indicate that there's something wrong, so it produces a *warning*.
- Async functions that reject will result in unhandled rejections, which should absolutely be avoided for the same reason that plain runtime errors should be avoided. If you had

  ```
  useEffect(async() => {
  await doSomethingAsynchronous();
  })
  ```

  and `doSomethingAsynchronous` rejected, you would end up with an unhandled rejection - because React does not do anything with the returned Promise, and you should implement the error handling yourself.

Comment: Thank you.  To your first point, I understand that `useEffect` expects either a cleanupm function or nothing ... but if you give it a promise it (seems to me) it treats it identically to if you returned nothing (or `null`, or `5`, or anything else except a `function`).  So I don't see the harm there.  As for your second point, I think that's a legitimate point if you are explcitly error-handling your callbacks with `try`/`catch` ... but if you're not (eg. in my example), I still see no harm.

Comment: first point is quite reasonable, second point not too much since you still have to implement error handling when using an inner asynchronous function

Comment: Well I think point #2 is (correctly) saying that you *can't* wrap the first form with `try`/`catch` ... but again, not every `fetch` needs to be wrapped in a `try`/`catch`, so it only seems like there's harm in the subset of cases where you choose not to error handle and use form #1 instead of using form #2.

Comment: @machineghost Sure, you, the script-writer, can see that it's safe *if* you surround all `await`s in `try/catch` - but React can't determine that, and I think it's not uncommon at all to see people assuming they can `await` while in an async function while forgetting to catch. React is being more strict than absolutely necessary for an app to run as desired, but it'll help catch potential problems earlier.

Comment: But, to get back to my question ... React "being more strict than necessary" is like the definition of a code "smell" (ie. something that might look bad, but may in fact not actually be bad).  So far it seems like form #1 is a "smell", and it limits my options (no cleanup and no error handling) ... but it works perfectly fine and has no actual harm.  Would you be willing to edit your answer to say something to that effect, ie. that there is no harm, but form #2 won't let you do the two things you mentioned?

Comment: @machineghost Yep, there are a lot of ways to write code that looks smelly despite actually working with no no edge cases - and React has decided to take the more strict route of logging a warning rather than hope that the developer knows what they're doing. Perhaps you can make the callback `async` if the script works. But React says not to do it, so there's a chance (I don't know how likely) that they'll make it result in an error in the distant future.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it is a bad practice to use async functions in use effects because:

1. The `useEffect` function expects to receive a function that returns another function to execute once your component is unmounted, rather than a promise.
2. As far as I know, non-handled async functions may cause some issues with states when your component is re-rendered, but your async function is not completed yet.

Comment: For #1, an `async` function is still a function, not a `promise` (it just *returns* a promise).  So either way, `useEffect` gets a `function` and not a `promise. For #2, I'm not asking about doing asynchronous work in `useEffect` (a *widely* accepted React pattern): I'm asking about form #1 vs. form #2.  How would the second form prevent that issue?

Comment: I was unclear. What I meant in #1 is that the `useEffects` callback expects to receive a function that resolves into another function, which will be executed when the component unmounts. When you specify that your function is `async`, you basically make your function return a promise.

Comment: Gotcha, so I can't return a cleanup function from an `async` function, which means form #1 prevents me from having a cleanup function.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, at least from what I know ;) Maybe in newer React versions they would let us use async functions for use effects

Comment: We can use them today :) ES Lint rules can be ignored or adjusted.  What's important isn't the rules, it's the logic behind them (which is what I'm trying to suss out with this questions).

Comment: Of course we can ignore eslint rules, but the logic behind this hook is what makes the difference. If react knows how to correctly handle promises, then I would use them, otherwise, I prefer not to mess with react, and return nothing from the function, and invoke the async function manually